# Postman pre-request everything is working fine as expected but facing below Undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

**There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

```
var limit = 50;
pm.sendRequest(getComponentsNewURL, function (err, response) {
   var jsonData = response.json();
   console.log(jsonData.contents[0].name); // able to get name here 
   for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (jsonData.contents[i].name == 'MyHTMLComponentName') { 
            component_id = jsonData.contents[i].id;
            console.log('component_id= ',component_id);
        }
        if(component_id){break};
   }
});
```

Comment: The size of `contents` array might be smaller than the `limit`. Changing that to `if (jsonData.contents[i] && jsonData.contents[i].name == 'MyHTMLComponentName')` might work.

Comment: @VigneshRaja Thanks for correcting me. It worked :)